# Binary Search C++

Tags: c++, binary-search

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly. It checks the bubble-sorted array for a user inputted number. I have it set to print out the numbers so I can can input a number I'm sure is in the array, but when I put in a number that I see is there, it almost always returns false. Sometimes true, but usually false. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
I have it set to print out numbers like this: number-index-

Thank you all so much for your help.

```
int main()
{
    int randomArray[20];
    int searchValue;

    //Irrelevant code snippet: Functioning code fills an array with random numbers between 0-60 and
    //bubble sorts them. User inputs searchValue.

        if(binarySearch(randomArray, searchValue, randomArray[0], randomArray[19]))
        {
            cout<<"The number you've searched for is in the array.";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"The number you've searched for is currently not in the array.\n";
        }

    return 0;
}


bool binarySearch(int arr[], int searchValue, int low, int high)
{
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int middle = (low+high)/2;
        if(arr[middle] == searchValue)
            return true;
        else if (arr[middle] > searchValue)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            low = middle + 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please post something *readable/compilable*....

Comment: Do you have an example of an array that you have given it where it has returned the wrong result? Have you printed the values that it visits in the list to see if it is doing what you expect? What have you tried to do to debug this?

Comment: I did have it printing out the contents of the array beforehand. It never occurred to me to print it out as the function was operating. I'll keep that idea in mind next time while debugging. Someone below fixed my function call. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your call should be like

```
binarySearch(randomArray, searchValue, 0, 19);
```

Comment: That worked. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much.